ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps' - How to make Django find my app?
I'm a Django beginner, also a new SO user, and want to register my app in settings.py.
Software version:

Python 3.11.9
Django 4.2.11

I created my app (named: Portal) following this guide: startapp with manage.py to create app in another directory
Here's the project tree:
C:.
├───media
│   ├───book-covers
│   └───users
├───static
│   └───admin
│       ├───css
│       ├───fonts
│       └───js
└───project
    ├───apps
    │   ├───auth
    │   ├───portal
    │   │   ├───media
    │   │   ├───migrations
    │   │   │   └───__pycache__
    │   │   ├───static
    │   │   │   └───portal
    │   │   │       ├───css
    │   │   │       ├───icons
    │   │   │       ├───images
    │   │   │       └───js
    │   │   ├───templates
    │   │   │   └───catalog
    │   │   └───__pycache__
    │   └───users
    ├───plugins
    │   └───tinymce
    ├───static
    └───__pycache__

However, when I register my Portal app, Django raised an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps'

apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PortalConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'apps.portal'

settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    '',
    'apps.portal',
    '',
]

I know this might be a duplicate question, but still I can't manage to solve this issue.
What should I do to make Django find my app? Please be as specific as possible because I'm totally new.
Thanks for your time.
I've tried steps here: Proper way to register apps in Django

looks like your Django project is in a non-standard way, which can lead to issues with module imports. try and use the standardised django project structure
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial01/

Thanks for your time. My Django project folder was Windows protected :)) I'll start again.

Update this code and check in
apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PortalConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'portal'

settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    '',
    'portal',
    '',
]


Add this into your settings.py
import sys

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps'))  # your 'apps' dir containing django apps


Thanks for your time. But this quick fix does not resolve my issue. I'll reinstall everything and start again.

Update: I realized my Django project folder was indeed inside a Windows protected folder :)) That maybe the source of all issues.
